# Как смотреть результат во время разработки react-native?

Tags: npm, react-native

Как смотреть результат работы при работе c react-native? Проект уже существует, и он без expo. Проект собирается Metro! При старте выдает вроде успех

> Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.
>   │ │
>   │ │  Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free
>   to        │ │  close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you
>   prefer.               │ │
>   │ │  https://github.com/facebook/react-native

Но что дальше? Мне нужен эмулятор как у экспо.